# Animate image "roll" using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, image, numpy, animation

In NumPy, there is a function called `roll`. The [documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.roll.html) describes it as follows:

> Roll array elements along a given axis.
>
> Elements that roll beyond the last position are re-introduced at the
> first.

Concretely, calling `roll` on an image could produce the following shifted version:

[image]

My question is how to achieve the same effect in JavaScript for arbitrary shift values along the width and height axes *and* how to make it animatable, such that one can see the transition from the original image to the shifted version.

Comment: `javascript` and `numpy` don't go together very often...

Comment: @QuangHoang Haha no. I want to visualize the operation on my blog and thought an animation would be cool. Tagging `numpy` might have been a little irrelevant to the question though.

Answer (score 0):

So the answer is embarrassingly simple. It can be achieved like so:

```
#imageDiv {
  background-image: url(the_image.png);
  background-repeat: repeat;
}
```

After which you can simply animate the `background-position` property on `imageDiv` (for instance `background-position: 42px 69px`).